# Can you add a new flexbox (or more items to a flexbox) on a button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been working on this program that tracks ones expenses (it is very basic as I am still a beginner). I am trying to have the expenses listed as a flexbox in a grid style but I don't want to have a set amount of spaces that you can list your expense in, my solution was to have a button they can click which adds a new row, or a new flexbox, under the current one but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I don't have the experience in JavaScript, or HTML, to be able to problem solve this so I haven't tried anything.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Frankly, flexbox is probably not optimal here. A `table` or CSS-Grid would be better but I'd aim for a `table` first.

Comment: Related: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout